# How do I extract a matrix of only positive numbers given a set of assumptions?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I want to divide a matrix:
`mat = {{a, 0, -b}, {d, a, 0}, {0, 0, -a}}`

with the following assumptions:
`a >= 0,  b >= 0, d >= 0`

Into two matrices, one containing the positive elements, and one the negative ones, given a set of assumptions.

I want to get:

`mat2 = {{a,0,0},{d,a,0},{0,0,0}}`

And:

`mat3 = {{0,0,b},{0,0,0},{0,0,a}}`

Comment: One way is `mat /. Times[-1, a_] :> 0` for the first, and `%-mat` for the second

Comment: `mat /. -1 :> 0`

Comment: "extract" how? additively, multiplicatively, quadratically, either or both?

Comment: My goal is to get any term with a minus sign into one matrix, and any term with a positive sign into another matrix. Even if they are part of the same matrix cell. For example:  
From the matrix _mat_  
`mat = {{a-c, 0, d-b}, {d, a-bc, 0}, {0, 0, -a}}`  
Get additively the matrices  
`mat2 = {{a,0,d},{d,a,0},{0,0,0}}  
mat3 = {{c,0,b},{0,bc,0},{0,0,a}}`  
Such that:  
`mat=mat2-mat3`

Answer (score 14):

```
Simplify[MapThread[Max, {mat, 0 mat}, 2],  Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, d > 0}]
(* {{a, 0, 0}, {d, a, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} *)

Simplify[MapThread[Max, {-mat, 0 mat}, 2], Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, d > 0}]
(* {{0, 0, b}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, a}} *)
```

Answer (score 14):

Using an undocumented function:

```
mat /. x_?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ :> 0
   {{a, 0, 0}, {d, a, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}

% - mat
   {{0, 0, b}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, a}}
```

Comment: The output for the substraction of matrices is not simplified, even after applying FullSimplify. Is there another way? Thank you for everything!

Comment: Can you edit your question showing the case you mention, and the result you expect?

Comment: The output for the subtraction of matrices is not simplified even after applying FullSimplify.  
  
I expected:  
  
% - mat  
    {{0, 0, b}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, a}}  
  
I got:  
  
% - mat  
    {{a, 0, 0}, {d, a, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} - {{a, 0, -b}, {d, a, 0}, {0, 0, -a}}  

Is there another way? Thank you for everything!

Comment: Did you run ``mat /. x_?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ :> 0`` and `% - mat` in separate cells?

Comment: Oh, done. It was specified before as MatrixForm for some reason. I removed that and it worked wonderfully. Thank you!

Comment: `MatrixForm[]` is for displaying things only. If you need to do further manipulations on a matrix, avoid it.

Comment: @LuisFernando you could also use  ``(-mat) /. x_?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ :> 0``   for `mat3`

Answer (score 5):

```
Map[0 &, mat, {3}]
```

> `{{a, 0, 0}, {d, a, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}`

```
Map[0 &, #, {3}] - # &@mat
```

> `{{0, 0, b}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, a}}`

Answer (score 2):

```
mat = {{a, 0, -b}, {d, a, 0}, {0, 0, -a}};
(mat2 = PowerExpand@ComplexExpand@((# + Abs[#])/2) &@mat) // MatrixForm
(mat3 = -PowerExpand@ComplexExpand@((# - Abs[#])/2) &@mat) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Alternatively, but perhaps not as robust,

```
(mat2 = (# + (# /. -x_ :> x))/2 &@mat) // MatrixForm
(mat3 = mat2 - mat) // MatrixForm
```